# ValueError: empty range for randrange() (9, 9, 0)" - Error in python

Tags: python

I wrote this code and I got this error :

error:

```
raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)) ValueError: empty range for randrange() (9, 9, 0)
```

code:

```
    a = random.randint(1, 10)
    b = random.randint(1, 10)
    if a == b:
        while a == b:
            if a == b:
                a = random.randint(1, 10)
                b = random.randint(1, 10)
            else:
                break

    c = random.randint(a, b)
```

I saw that another person asked about it but it didn't help me.

Comment: What do you expect from `randrange(9, 9)`?

Comment: From the error, which line is supposed to give the error ?

Comment: @azro the error comes from the fact that there's no guarantee that `a` isn't equal to `b`. In this case, the value just happens to be `9`

Answer (score 1):

You go to find a value for `c` when `a` and `b` are not same, but you can have `a>b` and it won't work, also your `if` are redundant with the while, you may do like the following to get something that works

```
a = random.randint(1, 10)
b = random.randint(1, 10)

while a >= b:
    a = random.randint(1, 10)
    b = random.randint(1, 10)

c = random.randint(a, b)
print(c)
```

And you'll get a `c` that is a random int, between 2 other random ints